# how to Remove the following redirect?

Tags: opencart

pingdom said me : 
Remove the following redirect chain if possible:
can you help me ?

https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id ... onse_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey

http://staticxx.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/r/lY4eZXm_YWu.js?version=42
Remove the following redirect chain if possible:

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?a ... e=en_US&numposts=4&sdk=joey&skin=light&width=600

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/feedback.php?a ... e=en_US&numposts=4&sdk=joey&skin=light&width=600

Answer (score 0):

That seems to all be happening on the facebook.com domain which you don't have any control over, so I don't believe you can fix this.